# Understanding (and partially disabling?) DNSSEC for an internal domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

I am setting up a new DNS infrastructure for our internal HPC cluster environment. This involves providing a migration path from our existing DNS authorities and domains.

For sake of example, let's say that we have an institutional domain of `example.edu`. (We actually have a real `.edu` domain.) Our group uses the subdomain `rc.example.edu`. I have set up a new internal authority for this domain at `ns1.rc.example.edu`, and am forwarding to that authority from our internal resolver.

```
zone "rc.example.edu" IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.225.160.10; }; # ip address of ns1.rc.example.edu
};
```

This works as expected. I can query my `resolver1.rc.example.edu` and get addresses for names in that domain.

```
[root@resolver1 ~]# host -t A ns1.rc.colorado.edu
ns1.rc.colorado.edu has address 10.225.160.10
```

But we have a legacy nameserver at `xcatmn.rc.local` that I want to also be able to resolve during our migration period. So I added this to `resolver1`'s `named.conf` to mirror the previous forwarding configuration:

```
zone "rc.local" IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.16.0.5; }; # ip address of xcatmn.rc.local
};
```

But when I try to query records from this domain, I get `SERVFAIL`.

```
[root@resolver1 ~]# host -t A xcatmn.rc.local
createfetch: xcatmn.rc.local A
validating @0x7ffba86868d0: xcatmn.rc.local A: bad cache hit (xcatmn.rc.local/DS)
error (broken trust chain) resolving 'xcatmn.rc.local/A/IN': 10.16.0.5#53
client 10.225.160.52#54752 (xcatmn.rc.local): query failed (SERVFAIL) for xcatmn.rc.local/IN/A at query.c:7004
createfetch: xcatmn.rc.local A
validating @0x7ffba86868d0: xcatmn.rc.local A: bad cache hit (xcatmn.rc.local/DS)
error (broken trust chain) resolving 'xcatmn.rc.local/A/IN': 10.16.0.5#53
client 10.225.160.52#37688 (xcatmn.rc.local): query failed (SERVFAIL) for xcatmn.rc.local/IN/A at query.c:7004
Host xcatmn.rc.local not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

If I disable DNSSEC in `resolver1` this query succeeds; but I don't really want to disable it for all resolution. At most, I want to disable DNSSEC for the `rc.local`. domain only.

```
dnssec-enable no;
dnssec-validation no;
```

Is this possible? I don't really understand DNSSEC that well, so I don't know why queries to `rc.example.edu` are successful (without my having done any kind of signing) while queries to `rc.local` are unsuccessful.

What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing in stead? (I know I shouldn't be using the `.local` domain. This is an attempt to migrate away from it, while supporting existing names in that domain during the migration period.)

Comment: Can you get any results for "rc.local" zone at all? What happens when you do ```host -t NS rc.local.```
.edu example refers to the external zone, and query goes online to the root servers, however you need to configure your rc.local on your local resolver as an authoritative zone, so it wouldn't go online for the results. Instead it should provide the result it has in cache or as an authoritative server.